# in ubuntu thunderbird unable to configure college mail id

Tags: thunderbird

Unable to add custom mail id I added server host and all things but unable to connect
[image: Add windows of thunderbird]

Comment: Server hostnames do not start with `.`  They could be something like `mail.vit.ac.in`, but you should check with your college to get the correct hostnames.

Comment: Yes i removed the period in front and i can able to configure in outlook why not in thunderbird with same domain name